# incron on Raspberry Pi

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi

I installed [incron](http://linux.die.net/man/5/incrontab) on my Raspberry Pi as you would any other package:

```
$ sudo apt-get install incron
```

I went to edit my incrontab...

```
$ incrontab -e
user 'pi' is not allowed to use incron
```

I checked the install of incron and, sure enough, it created a group named `incron`. Alright, so clearly I just need to add myself to that group and I'm home free, right?

```
$ sudo usermod -a -G incron pi
$ incrontab -e
user 'pi' is not allowed to use incron
```

Wrong. Thinking like a Windows man, I restarted my Pi with no luck. Any ideas, superusers?

Comment: According to the man page for the [conf file](http://linux.die.net/man/5/incron.conf) it looks like you add users to `/etc/incron.allow`

Comment: You want to post as an answer or should I just close this out of stupidity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the man page for the [conf file](http://linux.die.net/man/5/incron.conf), you need to add users to `/etc/incron.allow`